# Python to EXE file for Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I tried PyInstaller, but I was unable to include configuration  and .txt files in the package.

cx_freeze throws an error during installation and py2exe is not supported for Python 3.6 and later.

Which Python-to-EXE library can I use for Python 3.7?

Comment: Why is it off-topic?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because it's asking for a software recommendation ("Which Python-to-EXE library can I use")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)* supports Python 3.7.

The added data/txt files need to be read in the code like this:

```
open(sys._MEIPASS+ r'filename.txt').read()
```

It was taken from Stack Overflow question *[PyInstaller cannot add .txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885354/pyinstaller-cannot-add-txt-files)*.

Comment: It's using PyInstaller underneath?

Comment: Yep but you should install PyInstaller >= 3.4 version - It supports python 3.7

Comment: @Zid https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/blob/4e2d9a3f8532fd9fc483c379f8f20800a1eaf73f/setup.py requirements

Comment: I c. I installed PyInstaller with latest `pip`. With PyInstaller there are other folders created like `dist` etc. With auto-py-to-exe I didn't see those folders just 1 exe in output folder and a __pycache__in the script folder.

Comment: @Zid Auto-py-to-exe it's a wrapping on pyInstaller. After all operations you get only 1 `exe`-file. If you work with PyInstaller in `dist` folders you can see sources. But they not needed for launching exe-file

Comment: I see. Thanks for saving my time. I'm fighting these packages for last 1 hr. :D

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not able to call the read the packaged file. I included a simple txt file. I'm trying to read it with `print(open('file.txt').read())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195741/discussion-between-zid-and-frankegoesdown).