# How to circulate to many users who do not have python installed on their machine

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The script is prepared in `.ipynb` jupyter notebbok. I want this script to be used by many people but they don't have python installed on their machine or they are not aware anything related to python.

I would like to create a solution where they click and script will generate output for them.

Comment: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: There is no way to run the script locally without the language installed. If you just want to distributed as a document you can export it to something like pdf. If you need this to be interactive you can use a jupyter server and the users can visit using just their browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python to EXE file for Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818178/python-to-exe-file-for-python-3-7)

Comment: Thank you @allexiusw. I heard of creating exe package? Is this something possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: Yes, that's possible, check out the link to see options.