# Main KV File cant be found in Pyinstaller exe

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I'm at my wits end here... So I have a kivy app that runs fine from the interpreter and fine when built as a directory.  But it doesn't seem to matter how I build it, the resulting exe always fails to find my main.kv file.  My file structure is that I basically have images and a bunch of screens.

```
main.py
main.kv
resources/image 1
         /image 2
         /kv_files/screen1
                  /screen2
```

I have been over all the similar question on SO including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/44352931#44352931) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885354/pyinstaller-cannot-add-txt-files).  I think I have tried all of the options, most recently I have added

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
""" Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.environ.get("_MEIPASS2",os.path.abspath("."))

return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

to the top of my script and

```
 resource_path('main.kv')
```

just before 'app.run()'.  And at this point I feel like I've tried every other combination from the different suggestions.  Spec file is

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
 from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\nicks\\PycharmProjects\\Winapp\\main.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\nicks\\Desktop\\Winapp'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('C:\\Users\\nicks\\PycharmProjects\\Winapp\\main.kv', '.')],
         hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'win32timezone'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
a.datas += [('main.kv', 'C:/users/nicks/PyCharmProjects/Winapp/main.kv', 'DATA')]

exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('C:\\Users\\nicks\\PycharmProjects\\Winapp\\resources', 'DATA'),
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
      name='mainapp',
      debug=True,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True)
```

It seems whatever I try, the command line gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 147, in <module>
File "lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 288, in load_file
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main.kv'
```

in case its of any  use, line 147 is

```
GUI = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
```

So I can see why not being able to find it is a problem.  I've been over the PyInstaller docs about how a.datas and Tree are supposed to be structured so I think they are ok, but I still feel that there is somehting fundamental that I'm not getting.  Any help at all is gratefully received...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it. In my `main.spec` file, I specify my `kv` file like this:

```
         datas=[('gamescreen.kv', '.')]
```

Since it is in the same folder as my `main.py`, The full path is not needed.

To add the `sys._MEIPASS` to the resource path, I use (at the top of `main.py`):

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # this is a Pyinstaller bundle
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(sys._MEIPASS)
```

Also, just a reminder that the `pyinstaller` has some strange behavior concerning command line arguments. Note the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files) that discusses the limited options that actually have an effect when `pyinstaller` is run with a `.spec` file as an argument. Some command line options are silently ignored in that situation.

Comment: This got me most of the way there, needed to remove the a.datas  I also renamed my Kivy  file I think calling it main.kv was a problem.