# Pyinstaller adding data files

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I'm struggling with pyinstaller. Whenever I build this specific script with a kivy GUI and a .kv file, and run the .exe after the build, I get a fatal error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main.kv'
```

I've tried adding the .kv file, as well as a mdb and dsn file (for pypyodbc) using --add-data, but I get an error:  `unrecognized arguments: --add-data'main.kv'`. (There were more --add-data arguments for the other files mentioned.)

Are there any solutions for this or maybe alternative methods?

Answer (score 99):

As others (@Anson Chan, @schlimmchen) have said:

If you want to add some extra files, you should use [Adding Data Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

#### Two ways to implement

- Command Line: add **parameter** to `--add-data`
- Spec file: add **parameter** to `datas=`

  - Generated when running `pyinstaller` the first time.

    - Then later you can edit your `*.spec` file.
    - Then running `pyinstaller` will directly use your `*.spec` file.

#### `Parameter` Logic

Parameter in `--add-data` or `datas=`:

- `--add-data`:

  - format: `{source}{os_separator}{destination}`

    - `os_separator`:

      - Windows: `;`
      - Mac/Linux/Unix: `:`
    - `source` and `destination`

      - Logic:

        - `source`: path to single or multiple files, supporting [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) syntax. Tells PyInstaller where to find the file(s).
        - `destination`
          **file or files**: destination folder which will contain your source files at run time.
          * **NOTE**: **NOT** the destination file name.

          - **folder**: destination folder path, which is **RELATIVE** to the destination root, **NOT** an absolute path.
  - Examples:

    - Single file: `'src/README.txt:.'`
    - multiple files: `'/mygame/sfx/*.mp3:sfx'`
    - folder: `'/mygame/data:data'`
- `datas=`

  - Format: list or tuple.
  - Examples: see the following.

```py
added_files = [
    ( 'src/README.txt', '.' ),
    ( '/mygame/data', 'data' ),
    ( '/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' )
]

a = Analysis(...
    datas = added_files,
    ...
)
```

#### Your case

For your (Windows OS) here is:

- `--add-data` in command line

  - `pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;." yourtarget.py`

OR:

- `datas=` in `yourtarget.spec` file, see following:

```py
a = Analysis(...
    datas = ["main.kv", "."],
    ...
)
```

Comment: This is a great answer showing very clearly the equivalencies between the command line parameters and the spec file equivalents.  The examples are great.  Well done

Comment: If it helps anybody else, in my case I had a chromedriver.exe stored in a resources folder. My command --add-data line was thus: `--add-data 'src\resources\chromedriver.exe;resources.'` This then added a resource folder to the temporary MEIPASS folder, mimicking my actual directory.

Answer (score 62):

If you check `pyinstaller -h` for help, you can find `--add-data` option works like this `[--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]`. So in your case try

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;main.kv" yourtarget.py
```

Comment: Whether to use a semicolon or colon as the separator depends on `os.pathsep`, i.e., on most *nix systems this is a colon and on Windows this should be a semicolon.

Comment: with respect to the output dist/ folder, where did main.kv end up?

Comment: man pyinstaller docs could make that more clear ... all the examples i found used `:` ... usually i just do it in the spec file but i really didnt want a spec file for this project

Comment: The above will add a folder in the distribution path with main.kv inside of it like so: `distfolder/main/main.kv`. To fix this the command should read: `pyinstaller -F --add-data "main.kv;." yourtarget.py`

Comment: the comment from @Spencer is an essential part of this answer in my opinion, the answer in its current form is a bit misleading

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to run: `pyi-makespec yourscript.py`
Then edit the yourscript.spec script and add the files under datas in a= Analysis.

```
datas=[ ( '/pathToYourFile/main.kv', '.' )]
```

then run `pyinstaller yourscript.spec`
should be good after that.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Add comma then: datas=[ ( '/pathToYourFile/main.kv', '.' )],

Comment: @pmus I did tried with using commas too but didnt worked and showed the same error when I run the .exe file "too many values to unpack" error.

Comment: For future users, if you get 'too many values to unpack' make sure you are adding your path to the list as a tuple in the form `('source\dir', 'destination\dir')`. I missed this initially when reading the answer and got the too many values error.

Comment: I was experiencing the opposite of @BrandonBarney - Too few values to unpack - after adding my own image files to the package. After looking at the contents of `a.datas` from my autogenerated `.spec` file, I found that each tuple had an additional string `'DATA'`... so I had to use:

```a.datas += [('assets/icon.ico', 'assets/icon.ico', 'DATA')]```

This doesn't appear to be up-to-date in the docs.

Comment: Within the spec file, what can one add that's equivalent to the --onefile option at the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Next -F or --onefile option is assumed when running pyinstaller.

1. Note that (MacOS Monterey, 12.2 here) the expected folder hierarchy w/in you .app file will be similar to this,

[image: expected_folder_hierarchy]

pyinstaller does not add files nor create necessary folders into any of the folders of this folder structure; at least not in any apparent way. You won't find them.

2. However, when the application runs, a temporary folder is used under /var/folders which is very different from the folder structure in point 1. above. `print(os.path.dirname(__file__))` while running the application will reveal which exact temporary folder is used each time it runs. For convenience, let's call it `my_app_tmp_folder` i.e. your app runs under the folder `/var/folder/my_app_tmp_folder`

Then, pyinstaller adds data files or creates necessary directories w/in this temporary folder. In other words, when the application runs, all added files will be there and according to the specified folder structure (through `--add-data` option). `print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` will show system and application needed files and folders.

Bottom line: Files specified w/ `--add-data` option will be visible w/in `/var/folder/my_app_tmp_folder` when running and not w/in the *.app folder.

Some useful links from documentation:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file

Answer (score -1):

My application had this issue and a subsequent issue that is **likely**, if not inevitable.

## 1. --add-data for a kv file

Use `--add-data` as in the answer by crifan.

## 2. Kivy still can't find the file

Once PyInstaller has the kv file in the correct directory, Kivy still can't find the file.

**Possible Symptoms**:

- GUI launches, but screen is [black and empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467917/include-kv-json-files-while-packaing-kivy-with-pyinstaller-onefile).
- An AttributeError error that depends on the application code.

**AttributeError Examples:**

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable/36021330)
- My own case:

  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'`

Fortunately, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467917/include-kv-json-files-while-packaing-kivy-with-pyinstaller-onefile) solves the problem.