# pyinstaller: unable to load config file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a very basic flask application which imports a configuration file like so:

```
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

I'm trying to bundle this flask application using PyInstaller, which analyzes all imports to create its list of dependencies. Because `config.py` isn't explicitly imported, I believe I need to add it as an additional data-file. Per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files) I've tried the following:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "config.py:config.py"
```

When I run my bundled executable, however, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): 'Users/Johnny/config.py'
```

Everything works fine when I explicitly import the configuration file:

```
from config import *
```

But I'd rather figure out why my initial method isn't working. Note I'm running macOS 10.12.5 and python 3.4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to specify exactly where this configuration file is located, which changes when the app is bundled ([run-time information](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html#run-time-information)):

```
import sys, os

if getattr(sys, 'freeze', False):
    # running as bundle (aka frozen)
    bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # running live
    bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(bundle_dir, 'config.py'))
```

Also the command to generate the bundle via pyinstaller should be:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data './config.py:.'
```

which grabs `config.py` and adds it to the top level of the bundled app ([adding data files](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)).