# Is it possible to include my data Files into my Executable output during the packing py to exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

My data Files, including Images, Audios, Icons must be near my `.exe` file, without them I am not able to run my output, so how can I pack fully in one Executable File? By the way I am using `pyinstaller` or `auto-py-to-exe`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller -F -i <iconfile> <pythonfile>
```

If you put `-F`, you will get one file.

Comment: I know that, but I can't use my output exe file without other assets like background image, etc...

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files

Comment: Thank you for the link, but after attempting, it says successful, then it didn't work again when I moved away from the main directory folder to Desktop.

Comment: So it's not including my image file(s) inside the app, I think if there is no command which is packing fully as I would like, then is it possible to load that files via **URL**, when I open my ```.exe``` the image files load from the web automatically and allowing to use the app. Is this possible?