# bundle multiple python files to exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have 2 Python files, one is *runner.py* and other is *IntegrationV10.py* and some other Excel files for storing intermediate data.
In one folder I have all the above mentioned files.The *runner.py* file runs a infinite loop and inside the loop it calls *IntegrationV10.py* file every second.

The code for *runner.py* is given below:

```py
...
while True:

    try:

        os.system("python IntegrationV10.py")
        time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

break
```

I want to bundle *runner.py , IntegrationV10.py* and all the Excel files to a simple exe file. For this I run the below command:

```
pyi-makespec runner.py IntegrationV10.py
pyinstaller runner.spec
```

The exe file is created in *dist* folder and runs. But it shows error that:

> There is no file named IntegrationV10.py

The above message shows every time the runner.exe runs. I could not bundle IntegrationV10.py and excel files in the same exe file. However, when I copy paste IntegrationV10.py and excel files in the *dist* directory as runner.exe, it starts working. But I want to bundle them all together, not copy paste. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for pyi-makespec](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyi-makespec.html). You need to give it the name of a file that already exists. In other words, `pyi-makespec runner.py IntegrationV10.py` fails because "IntegrationV10.py" doesn't exist (or can't be found).

In your post, you alternate between "Integration10.py" and "IntegrationV10.py". If you replace `pyi-makespec runner.py IntegrationV10.py` with `pyi-makespec runner.py Integration10.py`, does the command work?

Comment: -thanks @ user697473 . it was a typing mistake. the actual name of the file is IntegrationV10.py. I edited the question once again. please have a look.
The runner.exe works if I copy paste IntegrationV10.py and excel file in the same folder as runner.exe. otherwise not. How can I bundle all the files :runner.py, IntegrationV10.py, and excel files altogtaher in single exe file so I don't need to copy paste?

Comment: "The runner.exe works if I copy paste IntegrationV10.py and excel file in the same folder as runner.exe. otherwise not." That makes sense. Can you edit your post to tell us about your folder structure -- the folder in which "runner.exe" is held, the folder in which the other files are held, and the relationship between those two folders? If you can do that, I think that it will be easy to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks @ user697473 I edited the question. The answer to your comment is: all the files (runner.py, IntegrationV10.py, excel sheets) all are held in same folder. when I  create exe file, a dist FOLDER is created and runner.exe resides in that folder. However, when I run the exe it shows the error message "There is no file named IntegrationV10.py". It solves if I copy paste 
 IntegrationV10.py in the dist folder. However, I wanted to bundle both runner and IntegrationV10.py in the same exe file so that  I don't need to copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pyi-makespec runner.py IntegrationV10.py
```

try this if you are using Windows:

```
pyi-makespec --add-data "IntegrationV10.py;." runner.py
```

Or try this if you are using Mac/Linux:

```
pyi-makespec --add-data "IntegrationV10.py:." runner.py
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files) is helpful.

To also add Excel files to the bundle, something like

```
pyi-makespec --add-data "IntegrationV10.py;." --add-binary "*xlsx:." runner.py
```

should work. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files for details.