# Missing dill was found using pyinstaller to compile executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I built a small program using sklearn, numpy and pandas, I tried to compile the file but it failed and have the following error message, it said there was a missing dll file in some location. I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files).

```
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 174, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI101722\sklearn\.libs\vcomp140.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sklearn111.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\dennis\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\dennis\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\_distributor_init.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 176, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\Dennis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI101722\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[6572] Failed to execute script gui_plus_model
```

So I put the dll it needs at the same folder with the .py file to be compiled, but the same error exist. The version of python is 3.8 and all modules needed have already been upgraded to the latest version.

```
pyinstaller -F --add-binary "vcomp140.dll;.dll" gui_plus_model.py
```

Comment: Please edit the text (i.e. NOT a picture of text) of the full error message into your question.