# How to convert python scripts to binary executable using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I am working on a project which has below directory structure

```
MyPythonProject
    -> configs
        -> appconfig.json
    -> logs
        -> app.log
    -> src
        -> file1.py
        -> file2.py
        -> file3.py 
    app.py
```

`app.py` is the main executable file which is also depended on python files inside `src`. I want to convert `app.py` to `app.exe` which I can easily do using `pyinstaller app.py`. This creates a `dist` folder which has python and all the packages. I can simply copy paste the `src`, `configs` and `logs` into dist and can easily share it with everyone.

But the problem is I do not want to share python files inside `src` as it is because it can easily accessed by anyone. I want to convert it into binary executable so that no one can convert or de-compile back into `.py` files.

For this, I can use auto generated `.pyc` files but I believe this can also be de-compiled back to `py`. Is there any way I can convert into some kind of binary which can never be de-compiled. Does pyinstaller do this. Is there any command available in pyinstaller which while converting `app.py` also converts rest of the python files into executable. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You could include the files into one executable using `--onefile` however I believe `pyinstaller` [can still be decompiled](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller)?

Comment: @PacketLoss Pyinstaller creates exe so I am sure it will be difficult to decompile. I will look at your link. But anyways can you explain a bit more on `--onefile`. Does using `--onefile` it also creates exe for other files

Comment: There is a good answer already on how to use multiple files in `--onefile` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710336/7942856) follow the answer to add more files, then include `--onefile` to compile into one executable.

Comment: @PacketLoss I am getting error in commands. Looks like I am not issuing correct commands. I am checking pyinstaller documentation as well but if you can answer, that would be great.

Comment: Are you importing the files in `src`?

Comment: @PacketLoss I am using this command `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'src/.*py:src' app.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221672/discussion-between-packetloss-and-s-andrew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing the additional scripts, `pyinstaller` will gather those imports and automatically include them.

You can use `--onefile` to ensure only the `exe` is created for distribution.

`pyinstaller --onefile app.py`

Comment: What should I use to prevent `exe` to be created?