# KivyMD with PyInstaller hooks - Images not showing in the standalone .exe

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language, kivymd

**GOAL**

I'm using kivymd with PyInstaller hooks in order to create the standalone .exe.

**PROBLEM**

Everything works fine in the standalone .exe except for the images that are not showing.

**Please note that the images show up in the application executed from the script, but not in the standalone.**

**LOCATION OF THE IMAGES**

Images are stored in a folder named 'media' and are linked with a relative path in the script. Please see the example below regarding "myicon.png" in the MDToolbar

```
MDToolbar:
    title: "My title"
    left_action_items: [['media\myicon.png', lambda x: None]]
    elevation: 10
```

**FILE .SPEC**

Following the documentation ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files) and [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)) for adding images/files in the standalone I created a spec file like this below:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
path = os.path.abspath(".")


added_files = [                      

    ( 'media\myicon.png', 'media' ) # Single file
    # ( 'media/myicon.png', '.' ), # Single file
    # ( 'media/myicon.png', '.' ), # Single file
    # ( '/media/data', 'data' ), # Folder
    # ( '/media/*.png') # multiple files # prova mia
    # ( '/media/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' ) # multiple files

    # ( '.\\media\\myicon.png', 'media' )  # # hookspath='.\\hooks\\',
]


a = Analysis(
    ["main.py"],                              
    pathex=[path],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    datas = added_files,     
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=None,
    noarchive=False,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=None)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,             
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name="myname",                       
    console=False,
    icon='myicon.ico'    
)
```

As you can see, in the "added_files" (list of tuples) I tried also other options (now commented out), but no one allows images to appear in the standalone.

At the moment I think that this issue might be related to one of two possibile issues:

1. The syntax is wrong (e.g. 'media\myicon.png', 'media' )
2. The logic related to the association of "added_files", "datas = added_files", "a.datas" is wrong.

Could yuo please help me to solve?
thanks in advance

Comment: try `( 'media/myicon.png', 'media' ) # Single file`. Note forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I have used the form:

```
added_files = [ ( 'media/myicon.png', 'media' ) # Single file]
```

Using forward slash.

And then at the top of my `main.py` I add:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # this is a Pyinstaller bundle
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(sys._MEIPASS)
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'media'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much John, it works now! I missed the "if getattr.." code.