# Unable to read downloaded file after converting python file to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, download, web-crawler, exe

I have written some code in python with the help of selenium which is doing web crawling in which it goes to a website after entering login id and password and downloaded a file. I have written the code in jupyter notebook with file name as `GSPL_Code.ipynb` and with the use of `!jupyter nbconvert --to script GSPL_Code.ipynb` and `!pyinstaller GSPL_Code.py`, I have first converted `.ipynb` file to `.py`  and then made a `.exe` file from the `.py` file.

If I run the .exe file which is named as `GSPL_Code` and it is stored in `dist/GSPL_Code` then a file `crv_report.xlsx` is downloaded in the `dist/GSPL_Code` folder where the executable file is also there but the problem is code does not executed after downloading a file in that location. It got stuck. Nothing is happening now. When I run in jupyter notebook then I don't face any problem but after converting it into `.exe`, I am facing the problem.

Please find the following python code which is part of the whole script:

```
    def handler(driver):
        curr=driver.current_window_handle
        for handle in driver.window_handles:
            driver.switch_to.window(handle)
            if handle != curr:
                driver.close()
        for handle in driver.window_handles:
            driver.switch_to.window(handle)
            print(driver.current_url)
        click_event('//img[@id="IconImg_crv_report_toptoolbar_export"]')    
        click_event('//div[@style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;width:249px"]')
        click_event('//span[@title="Microsoft Excel Workbook Data-only"]')
        sleep(5)
        click_event('//td[@class="wizbutton"]')   
        sleep(15)
        print("Report is downloaded")
        PATH1="C:\\Users\\ankit19.gupta\\Desktop\\Test_GSPL\\dist\\GSPL_Code"
        crv_report= "/crv_report.xlsx"
        print("Reading File")
        dataframe1 = pd.read_excel(PATH1+crv_report)
        print("Data is stored in the dataframe")
        return dataframe1
```

I have written some print statements to see where the error is coming. So, here I am unable to see the print statement `"Report is downloaded"`. Before this `click_event('//td[@class="wizbutton"]')`  is used to click a button which download the file in chrome browser and I can see this downloaded file in the path `dist/GSPL_Code` directory and it got executed successfully but after that it got stuck and nothing happened.

I am unable to find what is happening here. Can anyone please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: There were some delay due to which print statements "Report is not downloaded" and "Reading File" were not showing in console but now I am able to see it but it is unable to read the file `crv_report` which is on the path `PATH1` and it got stuck here and due to which I am unable to see print statement `Data is stored in the dataframe`

I think code is unable to access the file because `os.remove` is also not working when I try to delete the `crv_report` file. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: How did you make a .exe file from the python file? Did you just change the .py file type to .exe?

Comment: No, I have used pyinstaller to convert .py file to .exe. I have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Most likely a CWD problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625845/how-to-run-exe-file-from-python-script-converted-to-exe

Comment: Thank you. Now I can read the file and print() function is showing the statements but still "os.remove()" is not working for deleting the file though I have changed the current working directiory using os.chdir(). If possible, could you please help here also ?

Comment: Have you tried os.remove as a part of the file1.exe as described in the prior link?

Comment: Thanks a lot @LukeHamilton . Now all the issues are resolve. I didn't try that answer mentioned in the above link previously because changing directory was working fine. Thank you again for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OS Directory Change:

When refactoring python files, in your case changing .py to .exe, it's important to make sure **everything is a part of the current working directory**. Simple OS checker command:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

If directories are misaligned, you will need to run an OS command to **change the directory before interacting with any files**:

```
os.chdir('/your/desired/directory')
```