# Creating an .exe file when I have multiple .py scripts

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe, py2exe

I want to create an exe file off of my main python script, a GUI using PyQt5. I have used pyinstaller before, and it has worked fair enough when I had a single .py script. But this time my main script **calls other scripts** I have written (there is a General Class which has children in different scripts, and the main script creates instances of the children and then calls appropriate functions from the children or parent class depending on the buttons the user clicks)

Can pyinstaller handle that, and if so, how?

Thank you very much

I have tried PyInstaller before, but only for a single file. For multiple files I really have no clue.

Comment: what do you mean by "calls other scripts", you use subprocess or import?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I meant import.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very similar to your question:
[Pyinstaller module issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610049/pyinstaller-module-issues)

Please read the post and the answer and adapt it to your problem. Should work. If not, plz add error messages etc.