# Converting py and mp3 files to exe file

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert my python file (py) that contains an mp3 file into an exe file using the command:
`pyinstaller --add-data "song.mp3" --onefile -w final_file.py`
in 'windows powershell'.
So it showed this error:

> pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'song.mp3'

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "python file (py) that contains an mp3"?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870727/pyinstaller-adding-data-files answers your question, specifically the second answer.

Comment: I was writing a code and on of the lines will play an mp3 file using playsound('song.mp3')

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation clearly states](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=--add_data#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) that `--add-data` is for non-binary:

```
> --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
> 
>     Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable.
> The path separator is platform specific, os.pathsep (which
> is ; on Windows and : on most unix systems) is used. This option can
> be used multiple times.
```

use `--add-binary` instead

> ```
> --add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
>
>     Additional binary files to be added to the executable.
>     See the --add-data option for more details. This option can be used multiple times.
> ```

Note that if you include the file in the exe, you should [use the correct path](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0) in the code in order to find the file once the bundle is used.