# How to include image in Kivy application with onefile mode pyinstaller?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have been trying for the past 8 hours to get my image to show up in my .exe built using `pyinstaller`. My program is written in kivy. Everything else works, but the image doesn't show up. I have read [this][2] question. That has not worked for me. Or I just followed the answer wrong. If someone can please explain to me how to do it step by step, I would be very grateful. Also, if there is another answer, please consider telling me that as well.

I will include my ***main.py*** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class SayHello(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.size_hint = (0.6,0.7)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

        self.window.add_widget(Image(source = "say.png"))

        self.greeting = Label(
                        text = "Hello",
                        font_size = 40,
                        color = "#00FFCE"
                        )
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)
    
        self.slid = Slider(min = 0, max = 300, orientation = "horizontal")
        self.window.add_widget(self.slid)
    
    
        
    
        
        self.user = TextInput(
                    multiline = False,
                    padding_y = (20,20),
                    size_hint = (1, 0.4)
                    )
        self.window.add_widget(self.user)

        self.button = Button(
                      text = "Click me to greet you!",
                      size_hint = (1,0.5),
                      bold = True,
                      background_color = "00FFCE",
                      )
        
        self.button.bind(on_press = self.callback)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)

        return self.window


    def slided(self, event):
        self.slid
    
    
    
    def callback(self, event):
        self.greeting.text = "Hello " + self.user.text + "!"



def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(
        sys,
        '_MEIPASS',
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

path = resource_path("say.png")
        





    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SayHello().run()  


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467917/include-kv-json-files-while-packaing-kivy-with-pyinstaller-onefile
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the command you use to run `pyinstaller`.

Comment: I will add it today afternoon

Comment: @JohnAnderson Here is the command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "/home/maheswar/Desktop/sayhello/say.png:." "/home/maheswar/Desktop/sayhello/man.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your attempt to fix the path:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(
        sys,
        '_MEIPASS',
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

path = resource_path("say.png")
```

just replace that code with:

```
import kivy.resources

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # this is a Pyinstaller bundle
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(sys._MEIPASS)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Also, will the same EXE work on a different computer with same OS while including the image?

Comment: I have built `exe` files for `Windows` and sent them to people who could run them on other versions of `Windows`, but haven't had much experience along those lines with Linux.

Comment: Does this only work with image files or does it work with any type of file?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.resources.html): "almost all Kivy resources are looked up using the resource_find()". But I don't know specifically what this includes. It does not have a file type limitation.