# black console using py-to-exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, python-exec

i tried to make an executable file from my main_app.py using pyinstaller.
All works but when im duble click the .exe files generated its popping out just a black console, not the app..

This is the command i used:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w main_app.py`

Also i used and auto-py-to-exe all variants, and i have the same problem, nothing displayed on the .exe after double click, just the black console

This is how my project looks:
[image: directory files]

I have the main_app.py file that calls the others scripts from different subdirectories:

````
from gitscripts.main_git import gitmainfunction
from svnscripts.main import svnmainfunction
from jirascripts.jira_main import jiramainfunction
from confluencescripts.confluence_main import confluencemainfunction
print("\nWelcome to `Easy Datas`!\n")
print("Before trying to use the app be sure that you are connected to URA and ADN 2.0 !!\n")
print("Below are the current type of datas that can be processed: ")
print(" SVN (s)\n GIT (g)\n BUGZILLA (b) \n JIRA (j) \n Confluence(c)")


def main_app():
    subject = input("\nChoose for what datas do you want to make the final raport (s/g/b/j/c):")
    match subject:
        case "s":
            svnmainfunction()
        case "g":
            gitmainfunction()
        case "b":
            bugzillamainfunction()
        case "j":
            jiramainfunction()

        case "c":
            confluencemainfunction()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app()```
````

This is how the program looks using the IDE compiller vs .exe file:
[image]

He should display what is in the left corner, but isnt it .
In the main_app.py i just called all the function/scripts from those subdirectories.
If someone can help me solving this or if you know other way to make main_app.py to .exe

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto-py-to-exe for this, type `auto-py-to-exe` instead of `pyinstaller --onefile -w main_app.py` as this does not always work.

Comment: i tried also and auto-py-to-exe, and same, nothing displayed on the console

Comment: Give me a min and I will find a way to solve it for you. And if you have this in github share the link, I might get a solution to it then.

Comment: OK will find out what's wrong

Comment: It's a problem in your side from my end it work perfectly. And there is no solution to that. So sorry I can not help you @Champs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your external scripts in the build-process, as the subdirs with the scripts are not automatically available to your `*.exe`.

Please refer to the dokumentation:
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

This is also detailed in this post (just an example, there are a lot more):
[Pyinstaller not picking up Tree or Data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759444/pyinstaller-not-picking-up-tree-or-data-files)

Comment: yes, i did that but not working

Comment: You said you did that but in your command to create the *.exe ```pyinstaller --onefile -w main_app.py``` it is not included to copy the subdirs+data. Please check that again.

Comment: with the command yes, after i did wih ```auto-py-to-exe``` and i included and all the subdirectories

Comment: ok, lets step back and try two things: 1) execute your *.exe in an already open command prompt, so you can see the error message 2) try a --onedir build

Comment: known that i have multiple directories now, what command should i use?

Comment: the *exe to start is in your distribution folder. This distribution folder now represents what is extracted to a temp folder when using a onefile build. Search for the *.exe inside and run it. If auto-py-to-exe (or your build-command) was configured correctly and works like expected there should also be copies of your subfolders "bugzilla,..etc" inside the distribution-folder.  Does this work? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: no, i dont undestand, like idk why not working cause i have no errors

Comment: Have you tried a onedir-build and included your subfolder structure like described in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer from @ezpie shows that the issue is from your end. I'd suggest reinstalling pyinstaller. First uninstall pyinstaller: `pip uninstall pyinstaller`. Next Use the following commands seperatly to make sure your pip is fully updated:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

if `--no-use-wheel` doesn't work use `--no-binary :all:`

After this reinstall pyinstaller `pip install pyinstaller`

Now make sure you are running the exe in your dist folder and not your build folder. Finally, if this is difficult, reinstall auto-py-to-exe, and use that. If the problem still persists then I can't really help you furthur as it sounds like it is potentially an issue with your system. Hope this helps :)